# Lumen task scheduling without overlapping not working

Tags: laravel, task, scheduler, lumen

When I use withoutOverlapping(), it doesn't work and says

> No scheduled commands are ready to run.

I found only solution to remove scheduler-* file from directory:

> \storage\framework\

but there is no such file.
Please assist.

Comment: are you using an artisan command to triger the job ?

Comment: Yes, I am using this command "php artisan schedule:run"

Comment: add your custom command code

Comment: This is the command I am using
$schedule->command('leagues:grabber')->withoutOverlapping()->everyMinute();

Comment: run `php artisan` and see if your command its registered

Comment: Yes, command is registered. Its showing in the list

Comment: It runs when I remove "->withoutOverlapping()"

Comment: I think everything its fine with your command, use withoutOverlapping() only when you deploy the app.

Comment: I noticed the issue on the production server only then I tried to manually test on development server.

Actually, I have two tasks which should run parallel but shouldn't overlap with its own instance. So whats happening right now, first job takes 26 minutes to complete and then other one runs which should run every 5 minutes. Can you tell me other way around?

Comment: @jimmyShah did you fix this? I'm encountering the same problem. withoutOverlapping() enabled, the command does not run, and there is no file to be deleted.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the actual Command, for some reason it works on the others, even if I change the name on the scheduler.